# Type "Sentence" not defined in this script/block in UIMA Ruta

Tags: uima, ruta

I am getting a

> Type "Sentence" not defined in this script/block!

error when writing a "**Sentence**" block in "**main.ruta**".

Here is my uima ruta script:

```
PACKAGE com.example.test;
DECLARE ApplyBusinessCardKeyword;
WORDLIST ApplicationKeywordList = 'application.txt';
Sentence{->MARKFAST(ApplyBusinessCardKeyword, ApplicationKeywordList)};
```

This also happens with the "Paragraph" annotation.
Other annotations like "Document" work fine.

Any ideas of what I could be doing wrong?

I am using the latest UIMA Workbench (2.6.1) and Runtime (2.10.2).

Here is the full error stack:

```
Dec 13, 2017 5:02:25 PM org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl callAnalysisComponentProcess(434)
SEVERE: Exception occurred
org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.AnalysisEngineProcessException: Annotator processing failed.    
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.RutaEngine.process(RutaEngine.java:563)
    at org.apache.uima.analysis_component.JCasAnnotator_ImplBase.process(JCasAnnotator_ImplBase.java:48)
    at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.callAnalysisComponentProcess(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:401)
    at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.processAndOutputNewCASes(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:318)
    at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AnalysisEngineImplBase.process(AnalysisEngineImplBase.java:269)
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.ide.launching.RutaLauncher.processFile(RutaLauncher.java:242)
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.ide.launching.RutaLauncher.main(RutaLauncher.java:191)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not able to resolve annotation/type expression: Sentence
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.expression.MatchReference.resolve(MatchReference.java:132)
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.expression.MatchReference.getAnnotationExpression(MatchReference.java:173)
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.expression.AnnotationTypeExpression.initialize(AnnotationTypeExpression.java:59)
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.expression.AnnotationTypeExpression.getType(AnnotationTypeExpression.java:152)
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.RutaAnnotationTypeMatcher.getMatchingAnnotations(RutaAnnotationTypeMatcher.java:55)
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.RutaRuleElement.getAnchors(RutaRuleElement.java:51)
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.RutaRuleElement.startMatch(RutaRuleElement.java:59)
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.ComposedRuleElement.startMatch(ComposedRuleElement.java:76)
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.RutaRule.apply(RutaRule.java:63)
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.RutaRule.apply(RutaRule.java:54)
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.RutaRule.apply(RutaRule.java:36)
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.block.RutaScriptBlock.apply(RutaScriptBlock.java:67)
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.RutaModule.apply(RutaModule.java:56)
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.RutaEngine.process(RutaEngine.java:561)
    ... 6 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you need to create your own rules to annotate sentences and paragraphs, and from your example you're not doing this.

Check this link from the documentation https://uima.apache.org/d/ruta-current/tools.ruta.book.html#ugr.tools.ruta.language.seeding it contains the basic annotations of a RUTA engine

This example that create sentences is taken from the documentation

`DECLARE Sentence;
PERIOD #{-> MARK(Sentence)} PERIOD;`

For paragraphs it's a bit trickier, and if you checked the documentation you'll notice that they use some properties to check it (bold, for example), you'll need to create your own rules to find annotate them

Comment: Thanks, I did what you suggest in the end. I just thought "Sentence" and "Paragraph"  were embedded in the UIMA annotation schema as the documentation led me to believe. I also created the "Paragraph" annotation with the help of the BREAK annotation. I will accept your answer if there is no other answer in 24h suggesting a way to embed these (extra) annotations automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old Q but there is an alternative to creating your own, you can load and use a third party annotator that does it for you.

```
IMPORT PACKAGE de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.lexmorph.type.pos
    FROM desc.type.POS AS pos;
IMPORT de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.segmentation.type.Token
    FROM desc.type.LexicalUnits_customized AS token;
IMPORT de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.metadata.type.TagsetDescription
    FROM desc.type.metadata;

UIMAFIT de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.opennlp.OpenNlpSegmenter;
UIMAFIT de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.tokit.ParagraphSplitter;
UIMAFIT de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.opennlp.OpenNlpPosTagger;

uima.tcas.DocumentAnnotation{-CONTAINS(pos.POS)} -> {
    uima.tcas.DocumentAnnotation{-> SETFEATURE("language", "en")};
EXEC(OpenNlpSegmenter);
EXEC(ParagraphSplitter);
EXEC(OpenNlpPosTagger);
};
```